# Paste dictionaries to excel by specific key

Tags: python, pandas

I have few dictionares like this:

```py
a={2111:1,2112:3,:2113:0,2114:2}
b={2111:1,2112:2,:2113:0,2114:1}
c={2110:2,2112:5,:2113:1,2114:4}
d={2110:1,2113:0,2114:2}
```

I would like to paste it excel to gain something looks like this:

```
Index | A | B | C | D
2110  |   |   | 2 | 1
2111  | 1 | 1 |   |
2112  | 3 | 2 | 5 |
2113  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
2114  | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2
```

I can only do that for one dict in this way:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(data=a_dict,index=[0])
df=(df.T)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx',sheet_name="a")
```

I would be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create dictionary and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a={2111:1,2112:3,2113:0,2114:2}
b={2111:1,2112:2,2113:0,2114:1}
c={2110:2,2112:5,2113:1,2114:4}
d={2110:1,2113:0,2114:2}

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b,'C':c,'D':d})

print (df)
        A    B    C    D
2110  NaN  NaN  2.0  1.0
2111  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2112  3.0  2.0  5.0  NaN
2113  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2114  2.0  1.0  4.0  2.0
```

For replace missing values use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and if necessary convert to integers:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(di).fillna(0).astype(int)

print (df)
      A  B  C  D
2110  0  0  2  1
2111  1  1  0  0
2112  3  2  5  0
2113  0  0  1  0
2114  2  1  4  2
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! One more question. Is it possible to change NaN to 0.0 and how to rename columns ?

Comment: @Milek - `how to rename columns` - because columnsnames are defined in dict `{'A':a,'B':b,'C':c,'D':d}` be free change names like `{'col1':a,'col2':b,'C':c,'abc':d}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
a={2111:1,2112:3,2113:0,2114:2}
b={2111:1,2112:2,2113:0,2114:1}
c={2110:2,2112:5,2113:1,2114:4}
d={2110:1,2113:0,2114:2}

array = [a,b,c,d]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=array, index=['A','B','C','D'])
df.fillna(value=0)
df = (df.T)

print (df)

df.to_excel('dict1.xlsx')
```

Worked for me and 0 instead of 'NaN'